# attach form to javascript event without initially knowing the formid

Tags: jquery, html, forms, post, submit

I have a page currently with 2 forms and one jquery function that is attached to these two forms, after submit I get the id of the submitted form (one of those two) and perform some server stuff, the result is then used by the script to create many forms in the same page which a user can click on to submit and add to their profile. The point is I want to add a success message in a div in those forms with some db data after posting. I have to put a new javascript / jquery function on the page the problem is: how do I attach this new function to the newly created forms and not to the two forms statically present in the page? I am using some trick to generate unique forms id in these new forms example form id ="form123" or "form342" etc. The point is I need this id before hitting submit.

Answer (score 0):

Create jquery single parametrised function and pass id in that parameter by calling function from submit button like

```
onclick="submitFunc($(this).closest('form').attr('id'))"
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain what it does and add some references to it.

Comment: what should be the parameter? It's not clear to me... 'form'? @ELGavilan

Answer (score 0):

You could give all of your dynamic forms a class not shared by your static forms i.e. `dynamic-form`.

Then use the JQuery [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) event to attach a specific function to all of your dynamic forms before they have even been added to the page. If you went down this route then you would need to add the data for your success message in a hidden element in your dynamic forms when you are creating them and use the [load](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) event.

i.e.

```
$("body").on("load", ".dynamic-form", function () {
    var successMessage = $(this).find([class of hidden success message]).first().val();
    showSuccessMessage(this, successMessage);
});
```

Comment: hmm ok but how do I prevent the page to navigate to the url of post and show a blank page? I need to submit one dynamic-form and stay in the page.